# download file from internet through httpurlconnection method

Tags: spring-mvc, httpurlconnection

I am able to download files from a website . when i run it through java main method, file is downloaded and the response is

```
Content-Type =application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
Content-Disposition = attachment; 
filename = test.docx
Content-Length = -1
fileName = test.doc
File downloaded
```

But when i integrate it in my spring mvc application, it doesnt.. i get response as,

```
Content-Type =text/html; charset=utf-8 
content-disposition=null
content-length=-1
```

the file is not downloaded...
Please help me in getting through this.
Thanks in advance

```
    //code
    URL url = new URL(fileURL);
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "cookie-name");


    //add request header
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "test");
    int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
        String fileName = "";
        String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
        String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
        int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

        if (disposition != null) 
        {
            // extracts file name from header field
            int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
            if (index > 0) {
                fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                        disposition.length() - 1);
        }
        } 
        else 
        {
            // extracts file name from URL
            fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                    fileURL.length());
        }

        System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
        System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
        System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
        System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

        // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
        InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        String saveFilePath = "E:/" + fileName;

        // opens an output stream to save into file
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("File downloaded");
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("No file to download"):
   }

    httpConn.disconnect();
```

Comment: Can you give the two requests being used? the one that works and the other that isn't? the difference between them would explain why one works and the other doesn't

Comment: when i call the same method through java main method, it works... when i integrate this same code with my spring mvc, and deploy in tomcat it doesn't ... the response i get is...Content-Type =text/html; charset=utf-8.... this is wrong. it should be Content-Type =application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

Comment: The `text/html` response may be an error page coming back from the server (perhaps a 404) when sending from Tomcat/Spring. Can you confirm that the `fileURL` you're using is exactly the same in both cases? Perhaps you can add `System.out.println("fileURL");` and then re-run both tests.

Answer (score 0):

I got it worked. It seems that there was problem in the url which i called to download file. The url itself returned print response not download response that is why it was not working.

mistake was from my end...

Thanks to all who tried to help me.